# Проблема с Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

У меня есть такой вот запрос на Dapper `var list = db.Query($"SELECT * FROM [Table]");`
Как мне получить его в виде двумерного массива, что бы я могла обратиться вот-так `string str = list[0][0]` и получить значение по 0 столбцу и 0 строке.

Comment: А зачем? / Как вариант, можно заполнить `DataTable` с помощью [SqlDataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). И обращаться к нему: `dataTable.Rows[0][0]`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А можно ли с помощью Dapper?

Comment: `Dapper` - это ORM - библиотека. Он за кулисами делает маппинг SQL-выборки в объекты определенного вами класса. `Dapper` не предназначен для того, чтобы получать результат в виде двумерного массива.

Comment: Вопрос с заголовком `Проблема с Dapper` звучит странно. Тут точно проблема не в самом Dapper

Comment: @AndreiKhotko А можно написать так `db.Query($"SELECT * FROM [Table].First()`, и как потом получать по номеру столбца - list[0]?

Comment: можно сразу с запроса получить нужную ячейку - `SELECT FIRST(column_name) FROM table_name;` - как-то так

Comment: @Andrew Да я знаю просто прописав имя столбца в запросе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решается несколькими строками кода.

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();

using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader($"SELECT * FROM [Table]"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var row = new List<string>(reader.FieldCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            row.Add(reader[i].ToString());
        }
        list.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Всё, можно обращаться `list[0][0]`.